# How many graphs are possible on 5 vertices w/ no multiple edges or loops?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I think the answer may be $5! / (5-2)! 2!$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: I understand labeled now. Would unlabeled be different?

Comment: Unlabeled is quite different; now you need to talk about isomorphisms between graphs.  That is, if there is a triangle among three vertices, that's isomorphic to a triangle among a different three vertices.

Answer (score 3):

The number $\binom52=\frac{5!}{2!(5-2)!}$ is needed in order to answer the question, but it’s not the answer: it’s the number of pairs of vertices. Each of these pairs can have an edge or not have an edge, so to build your graph on $5$ vertices you must choose $\binom52$ times whether or not to have an edge. That set of $\binom52$ two-way choices can be made in altogether $2^{\binom52}$ different ways. (I am assuming that the vertices are labelled.)

Comment: aaah. I see. thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @Meowmix: You’re welcome.